# Como conseguir la ip del ordenador que estoy?

Tags: django

Hola tengo intención te coger la Ip del ordenador dónde este conectado.

Tengo este codigo pero me coge la dirección del servidor, y yo quiero que me coja la direccion IP del PC donde el usuario se conecte.

```
def getIPAddresses(self):

  hostname = socket.gethostname()
  ip_add = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
  return ip_add
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib
creo que esto es parecido a lo que te paso, él dice que cambies el `gethostbyname` del ip_add y lo remplaces por `socket.getfqdn()`